# Django / makemigrations ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'idmp_core.apps.IdmpCoreConfigdjango';

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm learning Django... And there is an error I'm not able to fix when running `makemigrations` command.

I got the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'idmp_core.apps.IdmpCoreConfigdjango'; 'idmp_core.apps' is not a package`. What is puzzling me is the `django` word appened at the end of `idmp_core.apps.IdmpCoreConfig` string that is part of

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'idmp_core.apps.IdmpCoreConfig'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

My project tree structure is the following one:

```
D:.
|   manage.py
|   
+---idmp_core
|   |   admin.py
|   |   apps.py
|   |   models.py
|   |   tests.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   views.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---migrations
|   |       __init__.py
|           
+---idmp_v0
|   |   settings.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   wsgi.py
|   |   __init__.py
|           
\---templates
```

I created the `idmp_core` using `python manage.py startapp idmp_core` and that went well.

I modified the `models.py` of `idmp_core` directory. And when I run the command

```
python manage.py makemigrations idmp_core
```

I get following error message

```
(idmp) D:\Dropbox\mycode\idmp_v0>python manage.py makemigrations idmp_core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\JMERX\Envs\idmp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\JMERX\Envs\idmp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\JMERX\Envs\idmp\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\JMERX\Envs\idmp\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\JMERX\Envs\idmp\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "C:\Users\JMERX\Envs\idmp\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'idmp_core.apps.IdmpCoreConfigdjango'; 'idmp_core.apps' is not a package
```

When I followed a Django tutorial, everything was fine. I did a mistake... But I'm not able to understand where...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just forgot to put a comma in there

Here you go

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'idmp_core.apps.IdmpCoreConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: This worked for me! Although could you explain why missing a comma results in a ModuleNotFound error?

Comment: Very silly mistake, a lot of people tend to forget, cos of autofill/predict/suggest options of IDE's. We subconsciously assume IDE does all that and we do not think of a coma that needs to be added. Huge time killer. Thank you for the eye-opener answer!!